# It is dark down (below)

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

There is a sentence "It is dark down below", which I met in a song.
Why is there the word "below"? What are the differences between

> It is dark down below

and

> It is dark down

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Down* can be attached to a verb of motion (like go, walk, etc.) to indicate the direction of the motion.

So we can say something like

> I've fallen down.
>
> I'm walking down.
>
> The water is going down.

*Down* doesn't work that way with *to be*.

You can say *it is down* because *down* also means "not working" or "not available."

But your example leaves a question open:

> It is dark down [where?]

*Below* means "a place beneath X or oneself" so that's why this works.